# datatable pagination work for first paginate only

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10, jquery-pagination

I am trying to paginate my data with data table plugin but its pagination works for the first time only. first, its loads showing data when I click on the second page it works but after that, it doesn't. it shows processing on the top of the table here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="data_table" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/></th>
            <th>Plan Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#data_table").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "response.php",
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']))
    {
        $start = $_GET['iDisplayStart'];
    }
    else
    {
        $start = 0;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['iDisplayLength']))
    {
        $limit = $_GET['iDisplayLength'];
    }
    else
    {
        $limit = 10;
    }

    $plan = new Plan();
    $result = $plan->getPlanList($limit, $start);
    $count= $plan->getCountPlanList();
    $myarray['recordsTotal'] =  $count[0]['count(*)'];
    $myarray['recordsFiltered'] =  $count[0]['count(*)'];
    $myarray['draw']  = intval($start/$limit)+1;
    $myarray['data']  ="";
    foreach($result as $data)
    {
        $myarray['data'][] = array('<input type="checkbox" name="selectcheck[]" class="selectcheck" value="'.$data['id'].'">',$data['name'],$data['description'],$data['image'],$data['quantity'],$data['amount'],'<a href="">Edit</a>');
    }

    echo json_encode($myarray);
    die;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: not getting any error on console. on console it sends request to server and get data but data is not drawn

Comment: You have to add `"pagingType": "full_numbers"`

Comment: You are having same numbers in `$myarray['recordsTotal']` and `$myarray['recordsFiltered']`.

Comment: yes. both are same number

Comment: adding "pagingType": "full_numbers" didn't work

Answer (score 1):

problem solved. I use sEcho value for draw on server side

```
  $myarray['draw']  = $_GET['sEcho'];
```